# could not display ${out.body} at Log for external soap provider

Tags: apache-camel

I already got reply from to uri which is external soap service provider. but why I could not see the response in log with ${out.body} i think soap is InOut exchangepattern, it should have out.body always. My code example looks like below.
Any hints are more than welcome!

```
<from uri="cxf://http://localhost:8080/myservice?dataFormat=MESSAGE&amp;wsdlURL=wsdl%2Fmyservice.wsdl" />
    <to uri="http4://localhost:8888/mockservice"/>
    <log message="##### After soap provider out.body ##### ${out.body}" loggingLevel="INFO" />`
```

Answer (score 1):

The OUT message of a previous processor becomes the IN message of your log processor.

I would recommend to simply not use the OUT message. As long as you only work with the IN message, Camel takes care of the out message (copies the IN message).

Quote from the book [Camel in Action](https://www.manning.com/books/camel-in-action-second-edition):

> In many cases, processors don’t set an out message, so in this case
>   the in message is reused.